# How to change a Python module name?

Tags: python, module

Is it only possible if I rename the file? Or is there a `__module__` variable to the file to define what's its name?

Comment: What's the problem with renaming the file?  Why won't renaming work?

Comment: Actually, it was just laziness... I didn't want to remove and add again the file on Launchpad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you should rename the file.  Best would be after you have done that to remove the `oldname.pyc` and `oldname.pyo` compiled files (if present) from your system, otherwise the module will be importable under the old name too.

Answer (score 29):

If you really want to import the file 'oldname.py' with the statement 'import newname', there is a trick that makes it possible:  Import the module *somewhere* with the old name, then inject it into `sys.modules` with the new name.  Subsequent import statements will also find it under the new name.  Code sample:

```
# this is in file 'oldname.py'
...module code...
```

Usage:

```
# inject the 'oldname' module with a new name
import oldname
import sys
sys.modules['newname'] = oldname
```

Now you can everywhere your module with `import newname`.

Comment: I can't think of a situation where I'd want to do that, but it's cool that you can  :)

Comment: One situation: a project where you want compatibility with both python 2.6 and 2.7, but want to use some new 2.7 unittest functionality. This trick allows us to have the code simply use `import unittest' while still using the new functionality, so we didn't need to modify a bunch of import statements everytime when switching python version.

Comment: Great.  example:
import tensorflow.keras  as tf_keras
import sys
sys.modules['tf_keras'] = keras
Then you will be able to use keras examples with tensorflow version of keras

Comment: I want this to be applied to an example like this: I have a module of pname and developed a modified module of pname_dev. In the running script I want to switch import pname or pname_dev for any situation and the script is using many lines of import pname.util.a, import pname.analysis.run .... Then rather than modifying all the lines of pname, I just want to change the origianal module to pname_orig, then let pname selectively indicate pname_orig or pname_dev. I expect this would work for it.

Answer (score 16):

You can change the name used for a module when importing by using as:

```
import foo as bar
print bar.baz
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `import module_name` the Python interpreter looks for a file  `module_name`*`.extension`* in PYTHONPATH. So there's no chaging that name without changing name of the file. But of course you can do:

```
import module_name as new_module_name
```

or even

```
import module_name.submodule.subsubmodule as short_name
```

Useful eg. for writing DB code.

```
import sqlite3 as sql
sql.whatever..
```

And then to switch eg. `sqlite3` to `pysqlite` you just change the import line

Answer (score 0):

Every class has an `__module__` property, although I believe changing this will not change the namespace of the Class.

If it is possible, it would probably involve using setattr to insert the methods or class into the desired module, although you run the risk of making your code very confusing to your future peers.

Your best bet is to rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

Where would you like to have this `__module__` variable, so your original script knows what to import? Modules are recognized by file names and looked in paths defined in `sys.path` variable.

So, you have to rename the file, then remove the `oldname.pyc`, just to make sure everything works right.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this with bsddb. I was forced to install the bsddb3 module but hundreds of scripts imported bsddb. Instead of changing the import in all of them, I extracted the bsddb3 egg, and created a soft link in the site-packages directory so that both "bsddb" and "bsddb3" were one in the same to python.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the module via **module** attribute like below.

```py
func.__module__ = module
```

You can even create a decorator to change the module names for specific functions in a file for example:

```py
def set_module(module):
    """Decorator for overriding __module__ on a function or class.
    Example usage::
        @set_module('numpy')
        def example():
            pass
        assert example.__module__ == 'numpy'
    """
    def decorator(func):
        if module is not None:
            func.__module__ = module
        return func
    return
```

and then use

```
@set_module('my_module')
def some_func(...):
```

Pay attention since this decorator is for changing individual
module names for functions.

This example is taken from numpy source code: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/0721406ede8b983b8689d8b70556499fc2aea28a/numpy/core/numeric.py#L289