# PyCharm - Dynamic Import Remapping

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working on some Boost-Build files (experimental Python build) and I'm trying to get the environment set up properly in PyCharm. Boost-Build has a [src](https://github.com/boostorg/build/tree/develop/src) folder with a layout like the following:

```
\---src
    +---build
    +---contrib
    +---kernel
    +---options
    +---tools
    |   +---doxygen
    |   +---types
    |   \---xsltproc
    \---util
```

When invoking the b2 executable, it does some [hand-waving](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/kernel/bootstrap.py) to set the `src` directory as an importable python module called `b2`. Then you can do python imports as you would expect:

```
from b2.util import bjam_signature
```

The problem is that in all of my python files, PyCharm doesn't recognize the `b2` package since, in reality, the `b2` package is just the `src` directory. So, I'm getting a bunch of `Unresolved reference` errors in PyCharm.

Is there anything I can do to get PyCharm to recognize the `src` directory as the `b2` package? (Without the obvious of just renaming the `src` directory to `b2`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best way nor the best PyCharm way, but I ended up creating a symlink called `b2` in my `Python27\Lib\site-packages` directory that pointed to the `src` folder. Now I don't get any errors about imports not being found as well as function completion.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is exactly as you mentioned. Just rename the src folder. You could also do something like

```
import src as b2
```

That won't help you do the **from b2 import** piece though. The other solution I found after digging a bit was in this post:

- [How to change a Python module name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590250/how-to-change-a-python-module-name)

Basically you can modify **sys.modules** to point to the new name. I suspect this may only work while the script is running, but you can give it a try and see.

Comment: The `sys.modules` part is already being done as a part of the [hand-waving](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/kernel/bootstrap.py) and doesn't help out with the `Unresolved Reference` errors I'm getting in PyCharm. And the `import src as b2` won't work either, since the src directory doesn't contain an `__init__.py` (I really don't want to alter the third party code).

Comment: That sounded like the way to go to me. I wonder if PyCharm's editor somehow overrides what is going in sys.modules.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for :\ I was hoping it existed.

Comment: You'll probably have to ask them directly. They're pretty good about getting back to their customers.